# Derivative of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac {12x-64x^3}{1-48x^2}\right)$

Tags: derivatives

How do you differentiate this function?

$$f(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac {12x-64x^3}{1-48x^2}\right)$$

I tried to change what's inside the inverse tan function to get the identity of the sum or difference between two angles but I can't get it right.

Comment: Do you know about chain rule when differentiating?

Comment: yes i know the chain rule but I want a quick way to approach the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a triple-angle rule: if $\tan\theta=4x$, $\tan 3\theta = \frac{3\cdot 4x-(4x)^3}{1-3\cdot (4x)^2}$. I'll leave it to you from there.